# Can a free action be taken in the middle of another action?

Tags: dnd-4e

For example, if a character has the [Quick Draw](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=157) feat and a weapon with a daily which takes a free action to activate, can the weapon be drawn as part of the attack and the power be activated all "as part of the same action"?

*"You can draw a weapon (or an object, such as a potion, stored in a belt pouch, a bandolier, or a similar container)* **as part of the same action used to attack with the weapon** *or use the object."*

In other words, can you use a free action of activating the power in the middle of the attack power?

Same logic would probably apply to using a free action in the middle of a move action.

Comment: Just for the specific case you cite, couldn't you Quick-Draw the weapon as part of the action of using its daily power?

Comment: There is also evidence for this in the interaction between Centered Breath flurry of blows and the at-will push attack of the monk.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. If your DM allows it.

> You can take as many free actions as you want during your or another combatant’s turn. There is an exception to that rule: A creature can take a free action to use an attack power only once per turn. ([DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/display.aspx?page=glossary&id=118))

You can do as many free actions you like on your turn. However, your DM reserves the right to limit free actions. The only RAW restriction to free actions is that you can only take one free action attack per turn.

Also worth noting as it has been discussed. Free actions can take place during other actions. They are things as simple as talking or making a small hand gesture. If its already a free action you can do it between the draw and the attack, even if the draw is part "of the same action" as the attack.

Lets take a different example. The Warden's marking ability is a free action that can only be taken on it's turn. One of the uses of this ability is that it can be used at any point during a movement, or even a charge. By a similar application of logic you should be able activate a free action magic item power during the course of an attack action (IE right before/during the swing).

Comment: That was basically my thinking. What I'm not 100% comfortable with is the fact that the free action happens in the middle of the other action.

Comment: if its a free action activate basically think of it as speaking the activation word/pressing the button as you draw it.

Comment: The _as part of the same action_ wording in the original question I disagree with.  They're two separate actions that happen to be in succession.

Comment: @okeefe, the wording comes directly from the [feat's benefit line](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=157): "You can draw a weapon ... **as part of the same action** used to attack with the weapon...".

Comment: @okeefe, I updated the question to clarify

Comment: @Eugene - my answer does not change. Yes its legal, yes you can, provided your DM has not chosen to limit free actions. You can do free actions at any time, even in the middle of other actions. I have updated my answer to clarify a bit, but the substance is still unchanged

Comment: @waxeagle, good point. the question should really be more generic... so I updated it to be more generic. feel free to update your answer. Once I see what others have to say, I'll choose the best and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing suggesting that any action can be taken in the middle of any other action, except for the special case of triggered and opportunity actions.